# Mapreduce query using in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm having 2 collection like association and associationrates. Bellow is my collection structure,
1.association

```
{ "name" : "MJDMA", "uniqecode" : "Mjdma", "address" : "Chennai", "phoneno" : "0448676788", "mobileno" : "98786766567", "emailid" : "mjdma@mail.com", "website" : "www.mjdma.org", "status" : "on", "created" : "January 19th 2014, 11:23:44 am", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52dbb5c0279f660000000001" } }
{ "name" : "Coimbatore Jewellery association", "uniqecode" : "CJAB", "address" : "Coimbatore", "phoneno" : "9787457363", "mobileno" : "9787457363", "emailid" : "rvkvino@gmail.com", "website" : "www.cja.org", "status" : "off", "created" : "January 19th 2014, 11:24:36 am", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52dbb5f4279f660000000002" }, "modifiedAt" : "January 20th 2014, 7:40:36 am" }
```

2.associationrates

```
{ "associationid" : "52dbb5c0279f660000000001", "gold22ct1grm" : "2803", "gold24ct10grm" : "29980", "silver1grm" : "48.30", "silver1kg" : "45150", "created" : "January 20th 2014, 11:27:39 am", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52dd082be7b9660000000001" } }
{ "associationid" : "52dbb5f4279f660000000002", "gold22ct1grm" : "3400", "gold24ct10grm" : "39789", "silver1grm" : "63", "silver1kg" : "61000", "created" : "January 20th 2014, 1:35:59 pm", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52dd263f1e82e20000000001" } }
```

I'm storing association id into associationrate collection for reference. I have to show associationrate details into jqgrid with the format of Association Name,Rate1,Rate2,Rate3,Rate4,Updated Date and Time and associationrateid.For that i have used the following code

```
var moment      = require('moment');
var associationrates = dbcon.collection('associationrates'); //dbcon is global variable of db object.
var association = dbcon.collection('associations');



  exports.getAllassociationrates = function(req,callback)
   {
var map = function () {

    var output= {assoname:association.findOne({_id:this.associationid}).name,gold22ct1grm:this.gold22ct1grm, gold24ct10grm:this.gold24ct10grm,silver1grm:this.silver1grm,silver1kg:this.silver1kg,_id:this._id}
    emit(this._id, output);
};

var reduce = function(key, values) { 
    var outs={ assoname:null , gold22ct1grm:null , gold24ct10grm:null , silver1grm:null , silver1grm:null , _id:null}
    values.forEach(function(v){
        if(outs.assoname ==null){
            outs.assoname = v.assoname
        }
        if(outs.gold22ct1grm ==null){
            outs.gold22ct1grm = v.gold22ct1grm
        }
        if(outs.gold24ct10grm ==null){
            outs.gold24ct10grm = v.gold24ct10grm
        }
        if(outs.silver1grm ==null){
            outs.silver1grm = v.silver1grm
        }
        if(outs.silver1kg ==null){
            outs.silver1kg = v.silver1kg
        }
        if(outs._id ==null){
            outs._id = v._id
        }
    });
    return outs;
};

    associationrates.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out: 'emp_dept'}, function(err, collection, stats) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err,null);
        }else{
            console.log("Collection:");console.log(collection);
            console.log(stats);
            callback(null,stats);
        }   
    });
}
```

But getting error like

```
{ [MongoError: exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: association is not defined nofile_b:2]
```

Please help any one, how to fix this problem or if there is any other solutions to achieve my expected output.

Comment: The `mapReduce` command executes on the MongoDB server. The `association` variable you defined earlier lives in the scope of your NodeJS application, and cannot be used in the Map/Reduce context. MongoDB (as at 2.4) intentionally does not have support for server-side joins in any context (including Map/Reduce) so you will need to work out a different approach. The solution to achieve your expected output from two MongoDB collections is to run multiple queries and join the data in your application code.

Comment: okey thanks, will do as your advice